# Masonry - deleting elements by clicking on something else, than the element itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

In Masonry, it is possible to delete an element by clicking on it. The catch is, that You have to click directly on that element - so if you use these "bricks" as an image gallery (as long as these photos are included as a background image) You can delete them, by clicking on the element. The problem is, when you use these as some messages/info/other content containers. Then, due to formatting-related stuff the parent element gets "hidden" behind other tags, and You can't actually click on it.

The problem is shown here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dan1410/SfU5T/
You can close red boxes, but not green ones, as they are overlapped by another elements.

I've tried code like:

```
eventie.bind( container, 'click', function( event ) {
// don't proceed if item was not clicked on
if ( !classie.has( event.target, 'closeable' ) ) {
return;
}
// remove clicked element
msnry.remove( event.target );
// layout remaining item elements
msnry.layout();
});
});
```

and

```
var todelete = document.querySelector('.closeable');
eventie.bind( container, 'click', function( event ) {
// remove clicked element
msnry.remove( todelete );
// layout remaining item elements
msnry.layout();
});
});
```

but You still have to click directly on the element You'd like to close...

My masonry content structure looks like

```
<div id="masonry" >
   <div class="item blue closeable">
     <div id="itheader"><h2 class="secsectiontitle">Space available</h2></div>
     <div id="itcontent">
        some statistics here...<br/>
        and here, too
     </div>
</div>
```

Only elements with .closeable class are supposed to be closeable.

So, the question is: how to close an element using a button/a link?
I'm not very familiar with JS, so I'd like to ask You guys for help. Thank You in advance!

Comment: I don't see any green boxes in the jsFiddle (firefox)

Comment: Oh, sorry, should work fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there are handlers that stops the propagation of the `click` event on children elements, the `click` event should bubble up without any issues.

Also, if you are using jQuery, you should use the jQuery Masonry's API.

*Note: I couldn't access your fiddle and couldn't test the solution*

```
var $container = $('#masonry').on('click', '.closeable', function (e) {
    $container.masonry('remove', e.currentTarget);
    $container.masonry(); //layout
    $container.masonry('reloadItems'); //OP said it was also required
});
```

Comment: Woah, it works on child elements, but it feels like you need a click to initialize that function. On my site it looks like the first click disables masonry for elements with .closeable class... I added the code to js fiddle. Also, what do You mean by "couldn't access"? Link issues? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dan1410/SfU5T/7/)

Comment: @RadioactivePickle I was in a restricted environment. It seems to work very well for me here http://jsfiddle.net/dan1410/SfU5T/7/

Comment: Just to be sure... What browser are You using?

Comment: @RadioactivePickle Google chrome. However since you are using jQuery, it should be cross-browser, unless the masonry plugin isin't. What is the issue with the fiddle I provided?

Comment: Hm, I'm using Firefox. How should I put it... It is diffrent on jsfiddle and my script: both cases require a click (that in jsfiddle does nothing, and in my script it looks like releasing elements with ".closeable" form masonry's influence), an after that - you can remove them freely. I have no idea why's that.

Comment: Okay, I messed with the code, and got the solution: I added `$target.masonry('reloadItems');` after the layout function in Your answer, switched to jquery syntax if it comes to initialising masonry, and it works perfeclty. Thanks for showing me the base for the code!

Comment: @RadioactivePickle If you are using `reloadItems` do you actually need  to call the `//layout` line?

Comment: Yes, it apparently checks, which items are left, and reorganizes only them. I had an issue that blocks were stacked like there were some invisible elements in there. Without layout()... well, it didn't lay out anything. This code works perfectly.